# Rails: URL helper to combine URL params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, parameters

How would I either create a helper or use the built-in `link_to` helper to combine URL params?

For instance, say I'm on a page with the URL parameter of `status`:

`http://example.com/items?status=new`

I have another link for carriers that I'd basically want to append to that, like so:

`http://example.com/items?status=new&carrier=fedex`

So basically the helper would detect if there were any params in the URL and then append the param to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the request object. Here is a good writeup on it:[Request Object in Rails](http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6377-action-controller-the-request-and-response-objects)

Comment: The link is dead. The answer from glebm below is much better anyway.